# Nginx silently fails to reload (98: Address already in use) but nothing else is listening on port

Tags: nginx, port

I am trying to figure this out for nearly 6 months now.
The issue is present randomly regardless of Nginx or Ubuntu version. The nginx-extras package is used from the Ubuntu repositories. This is a group of 10 servers with different hardware having this same issue.

In brief: Nginx will randomly fail to reload. The error log will reveal that it could not bind to address (currenly happening for port 443, but it also happens for port 80 randomly). Sometimes issuing `service nginx upgrade` will reload the server. If that fails too, `service nginx restart` sometimes will work, and sometimes not. When even this fails, the only way to reload the config is to issue `service nginx stop`, wait for a few seconds and then do `service nginx start`. None of these commands will ever return an error, insted they would return `[OK]` even when the command fails.

Stopping and starting Nginx is an issue as these machines are sending large files and the transfers get interrupted. In addition, if a large file is being pulled from the backend to be cached, during the restart the cached version will end up being corrupted.

```
nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
built by gcc 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: 
--with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro' 
--prefix=/usr/share/nginx 
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log 
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log 
--lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock 
--pid-path=/run/nginx.pid 
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body 
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi 
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy 
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi 
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi 
--with-debug 
--with-pcre-jit 
--with-ipv6 
--with-http_ssl_module 
--with-http_stub_status_module 
--with-http_realip_module 
--with-http_addition_module 
--with-http_dav_module 
--with-http_flv_module 
--with-http_geoip_module 
--with-http_gzip_static_module 
--with-http_image_filter_module 
--with-http_mp4_module 
--with-http_perl_module 
--with-http_random_index_module 
--with-http_secure_link_module 
--with-http_spdy_module 
--with-http_sub_module 
--with-http_xslt_module 
--with-mail 
--with-mail_ssl_module 
--add-module=/build/nginx-hzyca8/nginx-1.4.6/debian/modules/headers-more-nginx-module 
--add-module=/build/nginx-hzyca8/nginx-1.4.6/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam
--add-module=/build/nginx-hzyca8/nginx-1.4.6/debian/modules/nginx-cache-purge 
--add-module=/build/nginx-hzyca8/nginx-1.4.6/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module 
--add-module=/build/nginx-hzyca8/nginx-1.4.6/debian/modules/nginx-development-kit 
--add-module=/build/nginx-hzyca8/nginx-1.4.6/debian/modules/nginx-echo 
--add-module=/build/nginx-hzyca8/nginx-1.4.6/debian/modules/ngx-fancyindex 
--add-module=/build/nginx-hzyca8/nginx-1.4.6/debian/modules/nginx-http-push 
--add-module=/build/nginx-hzyca8/nginx-1.4.6/debian/modules/nginx-lua 
--add-module=/build/nginx-hzyca8/nginx-1.4.6/debian/modules/nginx-upload-progress 
--add-module=/build/nginx-hzyca8/nginx-1.4.6/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair 
--add-module=/build/nginx-hzyca8/nginx-1.4.6/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

Currently running process:

```
# ps ax | grep nginx
25771 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
29145 ?        S      0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
29664 ?        RN   516:47 nginx: worker process
29665 ?        SN   513:46 nginx: worker process
29666 ?        SN   514:17 nginx: worker process
29667 ?        SN   517:24 nginx: worker process
29668 ?        SN   512:29 nginx: worker process
29669 ?        SN   515:28 nginx: worker process
29670 ?        SN   517:52 nginx: worker process
29671 ?        SN   507:52 nginx: worker process
29672 ?        S      0:13 nginx: cache manager process
```

Attempting reload:

```
# service nginx reload
 * Reloading nginx configuration nginx   [ OK ]
```

Looking at ps output again, nothing has happened:

```
# ps ax | grep nginx
29145 ?        S      0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
29664 ?        SN   516:54 nginx: worker process
29665 ?        SN   513:49 nginx: worker process
29666 ?        SN   514:20 nginx: worker process
29667 ?        SN   517:27 nginx: worker process
29668 ?        SN   512:34 nginx: worker process
29669 ?        SN   515:31 nginx: worker process
29670 ?        SN   518:08 nginx: worker process
29671 ?        SN   507:55 nginx: worker process
29672 ?        S      0:13 nginx: cache manager process
31121 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

A check in the error log (IP address redacted):

```
2018/03/10 00:22:29 [info] 32481#0: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:95
2018/03/10 00:22:29 [emerg] 29145#0: bind() to 195.181.160.xx:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/03/10 00:22:29 [emerg] 29145#0: bind() to 195.181.160.xx:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/03/10 00:22:29 [emerg] 29145#0: bind() to 195.181.160.xx:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/03/10 00:22:29 [emerg] 29145#0: bind() to 195.181.160.xx:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/03/10 00:22:29 [emerg] 29145#0: bind() to 195.181.160.xx:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/03/10 00:22:29 [emerg] 29145#0: still could not bind()
```

The only process using 443 is nginx itself:

```
# sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :443
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443     0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN      29145/nginx
```

On these servers each customer has two server blocks - A public one, listening on standard ports, and an internal one that does the caching. The latter listens on a localhost IP, on a unique port and is accessed via proxy_pass from the public block. These internal blocks all proxy_pass to another locations themselves. The reasons for this setup are too complex to cover here.

What have I checked so far:

- All internal blocks can resolve their upstreams
- All internal ports are unique and are not being used by other services
- SPDY is not used (found a bug reported on Nginx's mailing list)
- Issue appears random, but tends to be more likely to happen the longer a Nginx instance has been running
- Behaviour present in both Ubuntu 14.04.X and 16.04, Nginx versions 1.4.6 to latest.
- No obvious relation to CPU, disk or network load

Example server blocks, as generated automatically by the platform that uses these servers (some information redacted):

Public block:

```
server {

    keepalive_timeout 10;

    listen 195.xx.xx.xx:80;
    #listen 195.xx.xx.xx:80 ssl;
    root /home/nginx;  
    server_name xxxxxx.xxxxxx.com ;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html

    error_page 403 /403.html; location = /403.html {
        return https://www.xxxxxx.com/403.php;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html; location = /404.html {
        return https://www.xxxxxx.com/404.php;
    }

    error_page 500 /500.html; location = /500.html {
        root /home/nginx;
    }

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        default_type "text/plain";
        return 301 http://xxxxx.xxxxxxx.com$request_uri;
    }

    location / {

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        geo_xxxxx     $geoip_country_code;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;

        proxy_buffering        off;
        proxy_pass             http://127.0.1.3:8213;

        set $sent_http_accept_ranges bytes;

    } 

    location ~ /playlist.m3u8 {              

        secure_link $arg_st,$arg_e;
        secure_link_md5 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx$uri$remote_addr$arg_e;

        if ($secure_link = "") { return 403; }
        if ($secure_link = "0") { return 410; }

            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        geo_xxxxxx     $geoip_country_code;
            proxy_intercept_errors  on;

            proxy_buffering        off;
            proxy_pass             http://127.0.1.3:8213;
    } 


    #ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live//fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    #ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live//privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    #include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    limit_rate 10000k;

}
```

Associated private block:

```
proxy_cache_path  /home/nginx/282-281-cache levels=1:2 
keys_zone=282-281:5m inactive=48h  max_size=500g;
limit_conn_zone $http_x_forwarded_for zone=addr282-281:10m;    

map $http_user_agent $blockedUA {
default 0;
"~thisisadummyua" 1;
"~thisisanotherdummyua" 1;
} 

map $http_referer $blockedREF {
default 0;
"~thisisadummyref.com" 1;
"~thisisanotherdummyref.com" 1;
}     

server { 

    limit_conn addr282-281 100;
    limit_conn_status 429;

    keepalive_timeout 10;

    listen 127.0.1.3:8213;
    root /home/nginx;  
    server_name 127.0.1.3;   

    location ~* \.(m3u8)$ {
            real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
            set_real_ip_from xxx.xx.xx.xx/xx;
            proxy_set_header        geo_xxxxx     $geoip_country_code;
            proxy_set_header       Host $proxy_host;
            real_ip_recursive on;

            # CORS setup
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

            proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
            add_header Cache-Control public;

            # allow CORS preflight requests
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }
            add_header Edge-Cache $upstream_cache_status; 
            proxy_cache            282-281;

            proxy_cache_valid      200 206 5s;
            proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating
                                   http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
            proxy_cache_lock       on;
            proxy_cache_lock_timeout 10s;
            proxy_cache_key        $uri;
            proxy_pass http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:41000;
    }

    location / {
            deny 10.10.10.1;
            deny 10.10.10.2;

            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

            proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control; 
            proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie; 
            add_header Cache-Control public;

            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }

            real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
            set_real_ip_from xxx.xx.xx.xx/xx;
            proxy_set_header        geo_xxxxx     $geoip_country_code;
            proxy_set_header       Host $proxy_host;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            real_ip_recursive on;
            proxy_set_header Range $http_range;
            proxy_set_header If-Range $http_if_range;
            proxy_no_cache $http_range $http_if_range;    
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_range $http_if_range;
            proxy_temp_path        /home/nginx/282-281-temp;
            proxy_buffering        on;
            proxy_max_temp_file_size 25m;
            proxy_intercept_errors  on;

            proxy_cache_purge PURGE from all; 

            add_header Edge-Cache $upstream_cache_status; 
            proxy_cache            282-281;

            proxy_cache_valid      200 206 5m;
            proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating
                                   http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
            proxy_cache_lock       on;
            proxy_cache_lock_timeout 120s;
            proxy_cache_key        $uri;
            proxy_pass             http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:41000/;


    }

    if ($blockedUA = 1){
        return https://www.xxxxxxx.com/403.php;
    }    

    #if ($http_user_agent = "") { 
    #     return https://www.xxxxxxx.com/403.php;
    #}

    if ($blockedREF = 1){
        return https://www.xxxxxxx.com/403.php;
    }  

    access_log /var/log/nginx/xxxx/xxx-xxx-proxy-access.log xxxx;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/xxxx/xxx-xxx-proxy-error.log;


}`
```

I am now considering to try the nginx-common package, but this are production systems. I am not sure if the issue would manifest itself on a test machine.

**EDIT:**
After asking this question I've decided to add a cron job to reload every 3 hours as my observations were that the issue is more likely to manifest itself the longer Nginx runs without a reload. It is the third day today with the cron running and all servers respond to reloads correctly and the problem is yet to be observed on any of them. At best, this is nothing but a band aid and is not solving the real problem. However, it is the best I've come up with and pretty much the only thing that seems to work.

**EDIT2:**
Adding a cron did not fix the issue but I had to try. I've then compiled Nginx from source with the least amount of modules we can work with and installed it on one of the servers. This was 7 days ago and this one server has not had the problem since then. As time is pressing me 3 days ago I decided not to wait any longer and started taking down production servers one at a time to replace their Nginx with the newly compiled version. So far so good and none of them show signs of the issue anymore. Let's hope I won't come back for a third edit.

Comment: Deep and difficult question.  Would your company support you getting support?  https://www.nginx.com/press/nginx-launches-commercial-support-its-world-renowned-open-source/

Comment: Unfortunately, this is currently not an option due to the nature of the business (A startup without VC funding with a constantly growing infrastructure needs).

Answer (score 0):

This happens from time to time. So nothing special about it.

We established following approach, if we like to restart or reload our services:

**1. Check if configuration is working as excpected:**

```
nginx -t
```

**2. Restart Nginx and check response:**

```
service nginx restart
```

**3. If restart was not possible because of port collission ...**

Check which service is blocking the port:

```
netstat -nltp | grep -E ':80\W|:443\W'
```

Kill corresponding service:

```
killall nginx
```

In some cases one process may be frozen. You have to kill the hanging process with more power:

```
kill -9 {process_id}
```

Comment: We already do something like this (we actually increment the value of a custom header in one server block to check if it has really been reloaded or not), but the main issue is that a restart would drop all active transfers and would also corrupt files that are currently being filled in the cache.